# Returning a type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I was attempting adding two lists, but thought to use types.

```
type x = int list; 

let add (elem1 : int) (elem2 :int) =
    elem1 + elem2;;

let add2Lists (a : x) (b : x) =
    List.map2 add a b;;
```

Surprisingly, add2Lists returns : x -> x -> int list. I know an int list is essentially the same as the type but how do I make add2Lists literally evaluate to values of type x?

Comment: Note that defining `add` is completely extraneous. You could simply write `List.map2 (+) a b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a type constraint:

```
let add2Lists (a : x) (b : x) : x =
   List.map2 add a b;;
```

For your reference, functions don't return types, they return (actually, evaluate to) *values of a certain type* (which may depend on the types of the arguments). So, your question should have said something along the lines of "how do I make `add2Lists` literally evaluate to values of type `x`?" Or, even more precisely, "how do I make the reported result type of `add2Lists` be literally `x`?"

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, new to the language. Can you explain what the ": x" part mean? 

Does that just say that I'm returning a value of type x? or is there any bigger meaning behind it

Comment: The `: x` syntax appears in several different constructs, but the "basic" meaning is always "I assert that whatever is to the left of the `:` has type `x`." The only question is what is to the left... in the case of the arguments, it's the `a`, then the `b`. The parentheses make that clear. In the case of the last `: x` in a `let` declaration or expression, it depends on whether a function (with arguments) is being created. If so, it applies to the result type of the function. If not, it applies to the pattern (usually just a single variable).

Comment: So, `let foo : int = ...` means `foo` has to be of type `int`, but `let f x : int = ...` means `f` has to be a function from something to `int`. It's a bit confusing, and not my favorite part of the syntax.

Comment: The `: t` syntax also commonly appears in signatures (`val foo : int`) and type ascription expressions (`(blah : int)`), the latter can be very useful for debugging type inference problems.